# Find near city based on lat and long

Tags: php, geolocation, geo

So let's say I this type of data:

```
  'Latitude' => string '45.798889' (length=9)
  'Longitude' => string '21.500833' (length=9)
```

Now I want to find some cities near this location is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

No need for anything complex in `PHP` use `Geospatial Indexing` is pretty easy to use

```
$col->find(array('loc'=>array('$near'=>array(45.798889, 21.500833))));
```

Other option include `$geoWithin` , `$geoIntersects` , `$nearSphere` etc